# Continuous Deployment with Azure and VSO Git Multi Project Solution

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have a solution in visual studio 2013.  It has two projects in it.  One is an mvc web app and the other is the models and other core components that the mvc web app requires.

I have this solution checked into a Visual Studio Online git repository.  All the projects are in the same repository.

I have the solution connected to an Azure website for continuous deployment.

The solution builds correctly.  However, when it comes time to deploy, instead of deploying the mvc web app, it deploys the core component project.

Anybody come across this and have a solution?

Comment: See this post for the answer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/95f161f6-9370-43ad-9ac5-714f8978cc5e/continuous-integration-deploying-wrong-project-from-solution?forum=azuregit

Answer (score 1):

It deploys the first project in the solution (the first one alphabetically).

So you either need to put your MVC project in its own solution and configure the Azure Continuous Deployment for that or make sure you MVC project is alphabetically first in the solution.

Not a great solution but that is just the way it works at the moment.